# SUM duplicate mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have a table with next columns:

```
ID |    Date    | Hours |
1    20-05-2013   8:00
2    20-05-2013   2:00
```

I want to SUM the duplicate's hours if have the same date.

```
  $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT count(distinct data_raport), SUM(ore) as TOTAL FROM sohy_works  WHERE data_raport BETWEEN '".$_GET['data']."' AND '".$_GET['data-2']."' AND numes LIKE '%".$_GET['numes']."%' AND ore <= '8:00' GROUP BY data_raport ");
while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
    $total = $row2[0];
    echo "8 hours/day: " . $total;

}
```

I want to print total of days with 8 hours worked. conclusion it's must to be 0 worked days with 8 hours because the raport have the same date (same day)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Date, SUM(Hours) as TOTAL
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Date;
```

**Edit:**

Hard to understand what you really want but this may help:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 8_Hours_day
FROM (
    SELECT Date, SUM(Hours) as Total_Hours
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY Date
    HAVING Total_Hours = 8
) T;
```

Comment: This is my code but don't work SELECT count(1), SUM(ore) as TOTAL FROM sohy_works WHERE data_raport BETWEEN '".$_GET['data']."' AND '".$_GET['data-2']."' AND numes LIKE '%".$_GET['numes']."%' AND ore <= '8:00' GROUP BY data_raport"

Comment: Please, update your question with theses details and add the error message.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(Hours) from Table group by Date
```

Comment: This is my code but don't work SELECT count(1), SUM(ore) as TOTAL FROM sohy_works  WHERE data_raport BETWEEN '".$_GET['data']."' AND '".$_GET['data-2']."' AND numes LIKE '%".$_GET['numes']."%' AND ore <= '8:00'  GROUP BY data_raport"

Comment: what your actual query prints ?? @RobertCoroianu